# yii portlet not able to render the view

Tags: php, yii

My `portlet` is unable to render the view;

This is how i call the portlet:

```
$this->widget('ModalConfirmDelete', array(
    'type_domain_or_url' => 'domain',
));
```

This is my portlet:

```
<?php

class ModalConfirmDelete extends CPortlet {

    public $type_domain_or_url;

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }

    /**
     * Renders the content of the portlet.
     */
    protected function renderContent() {
        $this->render(dirname(__FILE__) . '/views/modal_confirm_delete', array(
            'type_domain_or_url' => $this->type_domain_or_url,
        ));
    }

}
```

The view is located under the same directory as the portlet, but within the `views` child folder;

Why do i get the exception?

```
CException

ModalConfirmDelete cannot find the view "/var/www/html/HeadQuarter/frontend/protected/portlets/views/modal_confirm_delete"
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved; for some reason, the path was not needed;

I just wrote the view name;

On other projects I had to specify the path;